# Fixing mirror displayed tabPage in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have used this [Metro.dll](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwZj6dBfjNI_bEFmZ24xWDVLUkU/view?usp=sharing) to create the following TabControl
I want tabPages displayed as right to left on the top, 
But when i do it the text on the tab page displayed as mirrored as shown in the following Image
[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation it looks like the source code for this library of Windows Forms controls is at [GitHub](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/tree/master/MetroFramework/Controls). Download it and build it on your machine.

Look into the MetroTabControl class which seems to be extended tab control of the basic Microsoft's tab control. Particularly, look for the 
`TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, tabPage.Text, EffectiveFont, tabRect, EffectiveForeColor, EffectiveBackColor, TextAlign.AsTextFormatFlags() | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis);` method.

The important argument here is [TextFormatFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx) and it needs to be set to `TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft | TextFormatFlags.Right` when the tab control is mirrored or [RightToLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RightToLeftLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.righttoleftlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) are set to `Yes` and `True`.

As it turns out to be oversight in the source code of the library, you can modify it according to your needs and eventually submit a pull request to the project owner.